# no Angular o service.ts tambem é transpilado e executado no navegador mesmo não tendo um html atrelado a ele?

Tags: angular, segurança

a minha duvida é sobre a segurança do angular e regras de negócio, posso deixar algum tipo de regra de negócio no angular pelo menos no service.ts pois o service está rodando no node e não tem um html atrelado para ser interpretado no navegador, tenho essa duvida, alguém sabe me responder ? e uma duvida conceitual mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html, css e javascript são executados no browser.

Todo código que você escreve no angular irá ser tranformado em html, css e javascript e será executado no browser.

A transpilação ocorre somente na hora de passar de typescript para javascript (pq o browser não entende typescript e nem sintaxe do framework). Angular compila seus arquivos, minifica, junta em um arquivo ou alguns e está pronto para ser executado no navegador. O service é um arquivo js e será executado no navegador.

Qualquer código que você escrever poderá ser visto por alguém na aba source do F12, mas quando você builda pra produção, angular troca o nome das variaveis, minifica e faz uma série de etapas em relação a segurança. https://angular.io/guide/security

Aqui mostra conceitos básicos https://angular.io/guide/architecture como funciona a camada de visualização, ligação de dados entre um template, componente e assim por diante...

Comment: o que você está me dizendo é que não tem maneira segura de deixar um código no angular, é isso ? eu vejo api's em backend em NODE então essas API's não podem usar angular correto ?

Comment: Angular é um framework web para front-end, seus arquivos são executados no navegador. Node é uma plataforma para ser executada no servidor, não é possível criar api com angular (pq ele é um framework pra ser executado no browser). Você cria api's com node, java, .net, ruby... que disponibilizam dados para que o front-end possa ter acesso. Eles se conversam via JSON

Comment: Não faz sentido deixar dados sensíveis numa aplicação front-end, pq todos conseguem acessar sua aplicação... Mas se mesmo assim ainda é necessário, angular pode ser executado no lado do servidor (é chamado de Angular Universal) https://angular.io/guide/universal. Mas é um tema um pouco mais avançado... Abs